# How to ensure that server distinguishes two different TCP clients running from two different shells on the same computer?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, pthreads

If I run the client program from two different shells, how should the server be able to determine to whom he is talking to currently?

Platform: Linux, GCC

Client code: This client takes the host name as an argument.

```
#define SERVERPORT 3490
#define MAXDATASIZE 1000 

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int             clientSocketFD;
    int                 numOfBytesReceived;
    char                    receivedData[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct hostent                  *objHostent;
    struct sockaddr_in              serverAddress;

    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr,"usage: key in client hostname.\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if ((objHostent = gethostbyname (argv[1])) == NULL)
    {
        herror ("error: incorrect host name specified.");
        exit (1);
    }

    if ((clientSocketFD = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror ("error: socket system call failed.");
        exit (1);
    }

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port    = htons (SERVERPORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr   = *((struct in_addr *)objHostent->h_addr);
    memset (serverAddress.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddress.sin_zero);

    if (connect (clientSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof serverAddress) == -1)
    {
        perror ("connect() error");
        exit (1);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        if ((numOfBytesReceived = recv (clientSocketFD, receivedData, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1)
        {
            perror ("\nrecv() error");
        }

        receivedData [numOfBytesReceived] = '\0';

        if (send (clientSocketFD, "Get Lost", 15, 0) == -1)
        {
            perror ("send() error");
        }
    }
    close (clientSocketFD);
    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```
#define SERVERPORT 3490
#define BACKLOG 10

struct threadArguments
{
    int    threadId;
    int    listeningSocketDescriptor;
    char *message;
};

struct threadArguments threadDataArray [5];

void* genericThreadFunction (void* threadData)
{
    struct threadArguments *temp;
    temp         = (struct threadArguments *) threadData;

    printf ("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", (long) temp->threadId);

    while (1)
    {
        if (send (temp->listeningSocketDescriptor, temp->message, 14, 0) == -1)
            perror ("\nsend() error\n");

        char receivedData [14];
        int    numOfBytesReceived;
        if ((numOfBytesReceived = recv (temp->listeningSocketDescriptor, receivedData, 14-1, 0)) == -1)
        {
            perror ("\nrecv() error\n");
        }
        else
        {
            receivedData [numOfBytesReceived] = '\0';
            printf ("\nReceived: %s\n", receivedData);
        }
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int                 serverSocketFD;
    int                 newServersocketFD;
    struct sockaddr_in          serverAddress;

    struct sockaddr_in          clientAddress;
    socklen_t           sin_size;

    if ((serverSocketFD = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("socket");
        exit (1);
    }
    int yes=1;
    if (setsockopt (serverSocketFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("setsockopt");
        exit (1);
    }

    serverAddress.sin_family     = AF_INET;                 // host byte order
    serverAddress.sin_port       = htons (SERVERPORT);      // short, network byte order
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;             // automatically fill with my IP
    memset (serverAddress.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddress.sin_zero);

    if (bind (serverSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof serverAddress) == -1)
    {
        perror ("bind");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (listen (serverSocketFD, BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
        perror ("listen"); 
        exit (1);
    }

    pthread_t threads [5];
    int     returnValueOfPthreadCreate;
    long    threadId = -1;

    while (1) 
    {
        sin_size = sizeof clientAddress;
        if ((newServersocketFD = accept (serverSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &sin_size)) == -1) 
        {
                perror ("accept");
                continue;
        }
        printf ("accept(): got connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa (clientAddress.sin_addr));

        threadId++;

        threadDataArray [threadId].threadId                  = threadId;
        threadDataArray [threadId].listeningSocketDescriptor = newServersocketFD;
        threadDataArray [threadId].message                   = "Excuse Me, please!";

        returnValueOfPthreadCreate = pthread_create (&threads [threadId], NULL, genericThreadFunction, (void*) &threadDataArray[threadId]);

        if (returnValueOfPthreadCreate)
        {
            printf ("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", returnValueOfPthreadCreate);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit (NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

### EDIT 1.

Peername returns 0:

```
if ((newServersocketFD                                                 = accept (serverSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &sin_size)) == -1) 
        {
                perror ("accept");
                continue;
        }
        printf ("accept(): got connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa (clientAddress.sin_addr));
        printf ("\npeername: %d", getpeername (newServersocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &sin_size));
```

Comment: In which way you want to differentiate ...?

Comment: @pavun_cool I meant "any" way the server is able to determine to whom he is talking to currently.

Comment: You will be having different file descriptor for different client right...?

Comment: @pavun_cool Yes, but that descriptor is with the client. You want me to send that descriptor to the server?

Comment: Your posting's topic is quiet misleading, as it's **not** about the clients' creation **but** about how the server may distinguish them.

Comment: probably, you can look peerport() by that you can differeniate...

Comment: Another (formally misleading) issue is the naming of file descriptor in `struct threadArguments`. What you call `listeningSocketDescriptor` is *not* the listing socket, but the connected one (connected by being `accept()`ed via the listing socket `serverSocketFD`).Calling the `connected socket` an `accepted socket` might do also..., anyhow calling it `connected socket` suits betters as it's connected to the client's socket returned by `connect()`... ;-)

Comment: @alk thanks, have corrected the naming in the real code too. :) Any more corrections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client's ip-address and (**source**-)port, fetched as described below, do *identify a client(-connection) uniquely*.

If you are using address family `IF_INET` to create the `listen()`ing socket you can pull the client's ip-address and (the client's connection specific) (source-)port from the variable of type `struct sockaddr_in` which's reference was passed to `accept()` by using it's members `sin_addr` and `sin_port`each time `accept()` returns successfully.

Depending on the platform you are on, you need to change the byte order of such members (see man-page for `ntoh()` on how to do this). For directly converting the member `sin_addr` to a character array you are already using a method (`inet_ntoa()`) taking care of the byte order.

Using `getpeername()` on the file descriptor which was return by the successful `accept()` (and, in the context of the server process, is also *uniquely identifying the client's connection*) shall return the same values for ip-address and port of the peer as the call to `accept()` did.

Comment: Thanks, Indeed I am getting the different port numbers through accept command.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have a separate accepted socket (`newServersocketFD` in your code) per client.
If you use `getpeername()` on each, you'll find that they use different source ports.

Comment: Well, getpeername returned 0! `if ((newServersocketFD                                                 = accept (serverSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &sin_size)) == -1) 
  {
    perror ("accept");
    continue;
  }
  printf ("accept(): got connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa (clientAddress.sin_addr));
  printf ("\npeername: %d", getpeername (newServersocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &sin_size));`

Comment: @AnishaKaul:I suggest you take a look at `getpeername()`s man-page.

Comment: The information of the peer's ip-address and source-port is already returned by the successful call to `accept()`. (see my answer)